# CoreData - performance when having many relationships on an Entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I hope this hasn't been asked before, I searched for a similar question but couldn't find something that's close enough to my case.

Basically, my question is if CoreData can handle a big amount of relationships (by big I mean maybe up to 30 on some entities) while not being slowed down too much.

I have these entities (Just as a demonstration):

```
Resources (contains all Resources for an object)
ProcessA
ProcessB
ProcessC
ProcessD
ProcessE
... (many more)
```

These processes are needed for various tasks but nearly all of them need to have a to-one (or to-many) relationship to `Resources`.

Sometimes, they even need multiple relationships to `Resources` (`currentResources` and `oldResources` or whatever). That's why I need to add an inverse relationship (it actually causes problems if I don't have inverses. I don't know why).

Due to the inverses, the `Relationships` entity starts to look like this:

```
Resources
   someAttribute
   ...
   ---
-> inverseOfProcessA
-> inverseOfProcessB
-> inverseOfProcessC
-> inverseOfProcessD
-> inverseOfProcessE
-> ...
```

It's getting filled with inverse relationships that I will never need to access from this side (they just have to be there to prevent some strange things from happening).

I read into the concept of `faulting`. Is my understanding correct that when I fetch a `Resources` object, it doesn't actually load all the relationships? If so, how efficient is `faulting`? Because it does have to fill all of the relationships with `fault`-objects. That's the part I'm not really sure about. Does this impact performance when having many relationships on an entity?

---

I am sorry if this is a trivial question. The answer might be obvious, but I've just started worrying about performance and this interests me (and even though I read about `faults` in the documentation, this is not 100% clear to me)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're asking yourself if Core Data is going to struggle with your model, you have to ask yourself if your choices are good.
I don't know if Core Data can handle this, the answer is probably yes, but it depends on various other factors : are we talking about few entries or thousands of entries ? how many fetch requests ?

About your model : why not create a single entity Process with a way to distinguish a Process A from a Process B (with an identifier being an integer or a string) ?

About **faulting** : by default, when you create an `NSFetchRequest`, `returnsObjectsAsFaults` is set to **true** allowing you to work with large datasets without materializing all objects in memory. If you know that you're going to access all relationships, you can set this property to **false** in order to work with fully materialized objects, saving you bunch of round trips to the persistent layer.

Remember that Core Data *is just* a wrapper around a relational database so keep this aspect in mind to optimize your model and your requests.

Comment: I used to do just that (using one single `Process` like you said). It lead to ugly, complex and hard-to-maintain code (in my case, there wasn't a prettier way). Also, every process needs to have different kinds of attributes and relationships (say, `ProcessA` needs to save 3 strings and a Float while `ProcessB` needs 3 Integers and one date). I'd need to have many "general" attributes (like `string1`, `string2`,  `integer1`, ...) which would be ugly to work with as well. I had a workaround for that, but that was even more ugly.

Comment: That's why I switched to single-purpose entities which results in extremely clear and easy-to-maintain code and is way easier to work with. Someone told me, it's generally a good idea to always only have one single purpose for something.

Comment: I understand your problem but you'll have to find a workaround because even if you hold on a Resource object, how will you know which relationship points to the right Process ? Try to add other entities to break down your model into other pieces or use parent entities.

Comment: Thats the point , I dont need to know this. I will never need to access the relation from the side of the Resource object.